# Check if there are any empty files in a folder

Tags: bash, script

I have a script that downloads 17 files from a FTP server every time, but sometimes some files weigh "0" for some reasons.

So I'm searching for a bash script that checks if there are any files whose size is zero.

How could I do this?

EDIT: I would like to use an if-else statement: if there were any 0 byte files, I will have to run a bash script again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to list the 0-byte files, you can use `find`:

Example using `find`:

```
$ find . -type f -size 0b
./4.txt
./5.txt
./6.txt
```

The advantage of using `find` is that you can easily pipe it to `xargs` to do what you want with the files (such as deleting them), which is much easier than using a `for` loop.

If you are looking to do something with these files after finding them, for instance, deleting all of the 0-byte files (while accounting for weird file names), I would do something such as this:

```
$ find -type f -size 0b -print0 | xargs -0I file rm -v file
removed ‘./4.txt’
removed ‘./5.txt’
removed ‘./6.txt’
```

Additionally, another option to simply list all the files in the directory along with file size in human-readable format, use `du -h`.

Example using `du`:

```
$ du -h *
1.0K    1.txt
1.0K    2.txt
1.0K    3.txt
0       4.txt
0       5.txt
0       6.txt
```

**EDIT:**  As long as you know how to find the empty files, you can perform additional operations in a number of ways.  The following example may not be the best way of going about doing it, but if you are absolutely looking for an `if/else` statement, then you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *; do
  if [[ $(du -h "$i" | awk '{print $1}') = 0 ]]; then
    echo "$i is empty."
  else
    echo "$i is not empty."
  fi
done
```

Returns:

```
1.txt is not empty.
2.txt is not empty.
3.txt is not empty.
4.txt is empty.
5.txt is empty.
6.txt is empty.
```

Comment: @Giacomo - I have updated my answer to reflect your request for an `if/else` operation.

Comment: `wc -c` works as well, in place of `du -h`. :)